# htaccess no hidden redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have built a website with htaccess file and deployed it on two independent servers. Strangely, the httaccess worked differently.

httaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCompatibility2 On

RepeatLimit 32

RewriteBase
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.google.com [NC,L,R=301]
```

1)
*The server that acts as expected: replace the current url with www.googl.com
*The other one: concatenate www.google.com to the current url.

2) hidden redirect
patched the first problem.
Now, I want to do a hidden redirect to google.
I have omitted  the [R] attribute and:
*The "good" server does hidden redirect
*The other one doesn't redirect at all (no hidden and shown redirect).

Does someone has a guess?